# Is it allowed to use an undefined symbol in an unused constexpr value?

Tags: c++

The following code is compiled by both GCC (12.1) and clang (14.0).

```
#include <memory>

struct AB{};

struct AM
{
    void ra(std::unique_ptr<AB>  &&) {}
    void rd(AB const&) {}
};

AM amgr;

// Free versions of the above member functions
void fra(std::unique_ptr<AB>  &&) {}
void frd(AB const&) {}

template<typename T>
struct SUSMA : public AB
{
#ifdef SILLY
    constexpr static auto silly = static_cast<int>(T::meow);
#endif
};

template<typename T>
void rscma()
{
    SUSMA<T> sus;
    amgr.rd(sus);

    amgr.ra(std::make_unique<SUSMA<T>>());
}

template<typename T>
void frscma()
{
    SUSMA<T> sus;
    frd(sus);

    fra(std::make_unique<SUSMA<T>>());
}

struct SCM
{
    SCM()
    {
        rscma<SCM>();
        frscma<SCM>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    SCM scm;
}
```

If `SILLY` is defined, then GCC continues to accept it, whereas clang complains that `no member named meow in SCM` (which is what I'd  expect). What's even more strange is that clang also complains that `no viable conversion from 'unique_ptr<SUSMA<SCM>>' to 'unique_ptr<AB>'` and `candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'SUSMA<SCM>' to 'const AB' for 1st argument` (of frd).

https://godbolt.org/z/TqYGbhxd7

Can somebody explain why GCC accepts the use of an undefined symbol?

Also, why does clang complain about passing `SUSMA<SCM>` to an `AB const&` parameter, when it is clearly derived from `AB` ?

Comment: `Also, why does clang complain about passing SUSMA<SCM> to an AB const& parameter, when it is clearly derived from AB ?` i don't observe it with clang 13.1.6. Does it happen with or without `SILLY` defined?

Comment: `no known conversion from 'SUSMA<SCM>' to 'const AB'` happens when `SILLY`  is defined, with clang 14.0.0. Did you look at the godbolt link? clang with `SILLY` defined  is  the bottom-most compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. So both compilers are correct, but Clang is more correct.

`silly`, being a member of a template class, is instantiated only when used. And...

> [`[temp.res.general]/6.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1)
>
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> — no valid specialization can be generated for a template ... and the template is not instantiated, ...

Technically, the quote says "a template", while `silly` is a "templated entity", but I assume this to be a wording defect.